# Keras and TensorFlow: What means "Peer access not supported between device ordinals 0 and 1" and how to fix it?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have 2 GPUs installed and when i train a model i get the following message. What means **"Peer access not supported between device ordinals 0 and 1"** and **"Peer access not supported between device ordinals 1 and 0"**? Is it an error is it something i have to fix? I mean, the model itself trains successfully in the end. I think it uses only one of the GPUs, not both.  But i want to understand this message and fix the problem. Is there something i need to do?

```
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library cublas64_80.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library cudnn64_5.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library cufft64_80.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library nvcuda.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library curand64_80.dll locally
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "BestSplits" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: BestSplits
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "CountExtremelyRandomStats" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: CountExtremelyRandomStats
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "FinishedNodes" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: FinishedNodes
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "GrowTree" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: GrowTree
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ReinterpretStringToFloat" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ReinterpretStringToFloat
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "SampleInputs" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: SampleInputs
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ScatterAddNdim" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ScatterAddNdim
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNInsert" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNInsert
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNRemove" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNRemove
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TreePredictions" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TreePredictions
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "UpdateFertileSlots" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: UpdateFertileSlots
Using TensorFlow backend.
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 970
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.253
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 4.00GiB
Free memory: 3.31GiB
W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:590] creating context when one is currently active; existing: 0000022BB5DD0500
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 1 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 970
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.253
pciBusID 0000:02:00.0
Total memory: 4.00GiB
Free memory: 3.31GiB
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:777] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 0 and 1
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:777] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 1 and 0
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 1 
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y N 
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:916] 1:   N Y 
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 970, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:1) -> (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 970, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This just means that the gpus cannot communicate (pass information between gpu0 to gpu1 or vice versa) without passing the data back to cpu first.

Comment: ok, and is there a way to fix this so that they can communicate?

Comment: I mean both GPUs are installed correctly, drives are OK, both work as they should. Is there any reason why they cannot communicate? – RaduS 3 mins ago

Comment: For nvidia you'd need GPU direct.  I'm not sure if your hardware supports it or if you need some extra hardware.  Here's the link for more info https://developer.nvidia.com/gpudirect

Comment: You need two  Fermi- or Kepler-architecture GPUs.  Your GTX 970 is a Maxwell architecture so it's not supported by Nvidia.